# Unity rigidbody FixedUpdate basic movement does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement [this](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/moving-the-player) tutorial on the unity site. I've went over the unity blog and havn't found the solution to my problem there.

I have a simple `Rigidbody` sphere object over a plane.
The sphere is default sized, and set on: `(0,0.5,0)`.
The plane is also default sized, and set on the origin `(0,0,0)`. Those are the only components I use.
What I'm trying to do is to write a simple C# script behavior for the sphere that will move it across the plane, like so:

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody rb; // Holds the body this script is affecting.

// Called at the start, to set variables.
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); // Get the body, if there is one.
}

//For physical changes.
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float Horizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"); // Get horizontal movement from input.
    float Vertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"); // Get vertical movement from input.
    Vector3 Movement = new Vector3 (Horizontal, 0.0f, Vertical); // Declaring the movement I'd like to add to the RB. Y axis is irrelevant. X,Z - controlled by user input.
    rb.AddForce (Movement); // Making the movement.
}
```

}

I attached this behavior to the sphere, expecting It'd move when I hit some input key.

Despite this, when I play the project, everything compiles fairly well but the sphere just doesn't move regardless of what I type.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: If it's relevant, I also have problems opening the Unity c# code editor (forgot it's name). Whhenever I click open, it just instantly closes. I do everything on Visual Studio.

**EDIT 2**: My bad, I just figured out I have console Errors. I get the following one:

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Rigidbody' attached to the "Player" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
>   You probably need to add a Rigidbody to the game object "Player". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
>   UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3 force) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/modules/NewDynamics.gen.cs:706)
>   Controller.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/_Scripts/Controller.cs:20)

"Player" is the name I gave the sphere.

Comment: That error looks like it says exactly what the problem is, have you fixed this now?

Comment: @AdamH Yeah, nice name btw. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I forgot to attach the Rigidbody to the sphere.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NNOrp_83RU)